# odata format xml or json not working

Tags: c#, odata

i'm using c# with odata, but only output json format only,
how can i add query to show xml format, i tried below and not working,

i am using odata version4, i tried adding `config.Formatters` but not working,

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
    using System.Web.Http;
    using System.Web.OData.Builder;
    using System.Web.OData.Extensions;
    using wcod.Models;

namespace wcod
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            config.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select().MaxTop(null);

            builder.EntitySet<LiveMeeting>("LiveMeetings");
             builder.EntitySet<LiveMeetingByType>("LiveMeetingByTypes");

             builder.EntitySet<TimeMarker>("TimeMarkers");        
             var function = builder.Function("TimeMarkerSearch");
             function.Parameter<string>("meetID");
             function.Parameter<string>("keywords");
             function.ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<TimeMarker>("TimeMarkers");
            builder.EntitySet<MeetingInfo>("MeetingInfoes");

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();


            //config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata/v4", builder.GetEdmModel());
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.AddQueryStringMapping("$format", "json", "application/json");
            config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.AddQueryStringMapping("$format", "xml", "application/xml");
            config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata/v4", builder.GetEdmModel());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer that works for me,
on WebApiConfig.cs

ad the following two line

```
var odataFormatters = ODataMediaTypeFormatters.Create();
config.Formatters.InsertRange(0, odataFormatters);
```

and rebuild project and run 
try putting `?$format=atom` or `?$format=json` at the end of the query
if there're one more filter, please use `&$` instead.